# Can't get Datepicker to move to set date using a variable

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

Running jQuery 1.91 and Jquery UI 11.2.1 along with jeditables.

I've set up a plugin (which I found) for jeditables to enable the date picker, minor edit to it but it's functioning well in general.

I'm trying to set *either* the `defaultDate` or `setDate` options for the plug in based on an incorrectly formatted date input.

I have a function which takes the existing date text and reformats it to proper date picker formatting. However, even with the format correct, I can't seem to get the `defaultDate` option to see the new date string.

*Note: Due to datepicker issues, you have to click the <kbd>Run Snippet</kbd> button after every time the datepicker is called, so the page refreshes. That is a different issue entirely though.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//datepicker element
$('.editdate').datepicker('getDate');

//the datepicker initialization....
$('#main_container').on('click','.editdate',function () {
  $(this).editable("file.php", {
    indicator : 'o',
 submit : 'X',
    cssclass : 'edit_date',
    type: 'datepicker',
    event : "dblclick",
    onblur: 'Cancel',
    callback: function() {
 }
   });
});

//just shows the conversion of the text
$('.example').html(function() {
  var oTxt = $(this).text();
  var val = oTxt.replace(' ','-');
  val = val.replace(', ','-');
  var selected = convertDate(val);
    return selected;
 });


}); //doc ready


// ##### Datepicker!!!!!
$.editable.addInputType('datepicker', {
 element : function(settings, original) {
  var input = $('<input>');
  //var input = $('<input size=8 />');
  if (settings.width  != 'none') { input.width(settings.width);  }
  if (settings.height != 'none') { input.height(settings.height); }
  input.attr('autocomplete','off');
  $(this).append(input);
  return(input);
    },
    plugin : function(settings, original) {
        var form = this;
        settings.onblur = function(e) {
   t = setTimeout(function() {
   original.reset.apply(form, [settings, original]); }, 500);

  };
  
  //converts existing text to proper fomat
  var oTxt = $(this).text();
  var val = oTxt.replace(' ','-');
  val = val.replace(', ','-');
  var selected = convertDate(val);
  
  
  //Call datepicker
        $(this).find('input').datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    
      defaultDate: '"' + selected + '"',
      //defaultDate: new Date('"' + selected + '"'),
      //defaultDate: new Date(selected),
      //defaultDate: '2017-07-25',
    
        onSelect: function(dateText,init) {
         $(this).hide();
         $(form).trigger('submit'); },
        onClose: function(dateText, init) {
            original.reset.apply(form, [settings, original]);
            $(original).addClass( settings.cssdecoration );
            $(form).hide();
            $(form).parent().html(dateText);
            },
    })
    }
});

//convert text date to proper string
function convertDate(d){
 var parts = d.split("-");
 var months = {
  Jan: "01",
  Feb: "02",
  Mar: "03",
  Apr: "04",
  May: "05",
  Jun: "06",
  Jul: "07",
  Aug: "08",
  Sep: "09",
  Oct: "10",
  Nov: "11",
  Dec: "12"
 };
 return parts[2]+"-"+months[parts[0]]+"-"+parts[1];
}
```

```css
div { padding: 20px; background: #eee; }
.editdate { float: left; cursor: pointer; display: block; padding: 5px 8px; font-size: 14px; width: 100px; background: #aaa; color: #fff; text-align: center;margin-right: 20px;}
.code { display: block; background: #eee; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/1.7.3/jeditable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="main_container">
<span class="bx airdate">
 <span class="editdate airdatet" id="ep_date-02" data="02">Jul 25, 2017</span> <-- double-click to call datepicker
</span>
</div>

<p>Double click the date.... desire is to have datepicker open with <em>that</em> date <strong>selected</strong>.</p>

<p>Note the lines in the plugin function:</p>
<p class="code">defaultDate: '"' + selected + '"',<br />
      //defaultDate: new Date('"' + selected + '"'),<br />
      //defaultDate: new Date(selected),<br />
      //defaultDate: '2017-07-25',</p>
<p>If you uncomment the last line, things work. None of the others will. <strong>I can't get the variable to work.</strong></p>

<p>Example of what the text conversion outputs:</p>
<p class="example code" id="ep_date-02" data="02">Jul 25, 2017</p>
<p>So it seems to be more a matter of placement of the javascript.</p>
```

Note the lines in the plugin function:

```
defaultDate: '"' + selected + '"',
//defaultDate: new Date('"' + selected + '"'),
//defaultDate: new Date(selected),
//defaultDate: '2017-07-25',
```

I've also tried various formats using `String()`, `toPrimitive()`, and `toString()`. I was unable to get those working as well.

If you uncomment the last line, things work. None of the others will.

I can't get the variable to work.

I've also tried moving this to the actual doc ready datepicker initialization function, nothing works with the variable there either. I've also spend a great deal of time going over *anything* here related to the datepicker with no luck.

Can someone please tell me where I'm faltering??

*[jsFiddle is here if you'd rather play there](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/8564azb8/1/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue:

```
defaultDate: '"' + selected + '"',
```

depends on the following line:

```
var oTxt = $(this).text();
```

Change that line to:

```
var oTxt = $(this).find('input').val();
```

***This*** in this case refers to the form.edit_date and so it is wrong.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.editdate').datepicker('getDate');

    $('#main_container').on('click','.editdate',function () {
        $(this).editable("file.php", {
            indicator : 'o',
            submit : 'X',
            cssclass : 'edit_date',
            type: 'datepicker',
            event : "dblclick",
            onblur: 'Cancel',
            // defaultDate: convertDate(oTxt),
            callback: function() {
            }
        });
    });


}); //doc ready


// ##### Datepicker!!!!!
$.editable.addInputType('datepicker', {
    element : function(settings, original) {
        var input = $('<input>');
        //var input = $('<input size=8 />');
        if (settings.width  != 'none') { input.width(settings.width);  }
        if (settings.height != 'none') { input.height(settings.height); }
        input.attr('autocomplete','off');
        $(this).append(input);
        return(input);
    },
    plugin : function(settings, original) {
        /* Workaround for missing parentNode in IE */
        var form = this;
        //settings.onblur = 'submit';
        settings.onblur = function(e) {
            t = setTimeout(function() {
                original.reset.apply(form, [settings, original]); }, 500);

        };

        //converts existing text to proper fomat
        var oTxt = $(this).find('input').val();
        var val = oTxt.replace(' ','-');
        val = val.replace(', ','-');
        var selected = convertDate(val);


        //Call datepicker
        $(this).find('input').datepicker({
            firstDay: 0,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

            defaultDate: new Date('"' + selected + '"'),
            //defaultDate: '2017-07-25',

            onSelect: function(dateText,init) {
                $(this).hide();
                $(form).trigger('submit'); },
            onClose: function(dateText, init) {
                original.reset.apply(form, [settings, original]);
                $(original).addClass( settings.cssdecoration );
                $(form).hide();
                $(form).parent().html(dateText);
            },
        })
    }
});

//convert text date to proper string
function convertDate(d){
    var parts = d.split("-");
    var months = {
        Jan: "01",
        Feb: "02",
        Mar: "03",
        Apr: "04",
        May: "05",
        Jun: "06",
        Jul: "07",
        Aug: "08",
        Sep: "09",
        Oct: "10",
        Nov: "11",
        Dec: "12"
    };
    return parts[2]+"-"+months[parts[0]]+"-"+parts[1];
}
```

```css
div { padding: 20px; background: #eee; }
.editdate { cursor: pointer; display: block; padding: 5px 8px; font-size: 14px; width: 100px; background: #aaa; color: #fff; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/1.7.3/jeditable.min.js"></script>


<div id="main_container">

<span class="bx airdate">

 <span class="editdate airdatet" id="ep_date-02" data="02">Jul 25, 2017</span>

</span>

</div>
```

Comment: **THANK YOU!** I knew I kept overlooking something but couldn't find it for the life of me. This solves the issue. Much appreciated. I did have to use `$(this).find('input').text();` rather than `val()'. but it's working. Thanks again!